# Bot Framework Emulator - Add new members

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm struggling with Microsoft bots for teams and need to use the `TeamsInfo.getMember(turnContext, 'example@my@.com)` method.

Instead I've been looking at `TeamsInfo.getMembers(turnContex)` which returns all users which is as below:

```
[
  {
    id: '0b971500-986d-11eb-b677-9f834e5213c4',
    name: 'Bot',
    aadObjectId: undefined
  },
  {
    id: '62151113-02ad-409a-91a8-c651db2c1af5',
    name: 'User',
    aadObjectId: undefined
  }
]
```

I want to be able to add a email address to my members on the emulator but can't for the life of me find anything on how to do this on the bot framework emulator.

So my question is hopefully simple. How do I add more members to my emulator with an email address property so I can test the `TeamsInfo.getMember(turnContext, 'example@my@.com)` method locally.

Ta

Comment: Hi @MaxwellLynn, It is not possible to test locally  you need to configure your bot to teams channel to test TeamsInfo.getMember(turnContext, 'example@my@.com) method.

Answer (score 0):

**Coping answer from comments for better visibility**

Hi @MaxwellLynn, It is not possible to test locally you need to configure your bot to teams channel to test TeamsInfo.getMember(turnContext, 'example@my@.com) method.